# php regex first part is specified string, second part are pure digital

Tags: php, regex

I want use regex to make a judge, if some sring's structure is made `'num/' + digital`(**no matter how long the digital is, but it should be a pure digital.** & First part should be 'num/')

My basic code below:

```
$str='num/1234';
if(preg_match("/num\/\d/",$str)){
    echo 'ok';  
}else{
    echo 'no';
}
```

My wish is:

> something like num/1234 or num/567890 are ok
>
> something like nums/1234 or num_567890 are no
>
> something like num/1234a or num/56_7890 are no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a `+` quantifier after `\d`, and include `^` and `$` to make sure that's all that is contained in the string:

```
/^num\/\d+$/
```